# How can I handle box drawing characters?

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding

I must generate files for windows batch scripting, modifying template files, es.

```
dataIn = Import["template.bat","Lines"];
dataOut = aFunction[dataIn];
Export["aScript.bat",dataOut,"Lines"];
```

The problem comes from 
the box drawing characters (see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character )
in template.bat, because they are never diplayed rightly.

I have tried:

```
test[dataIn_, encoding_] := Export[
   encoding <> ".bat",
   StringJoin @ FromCharacterCode[
     ToCharacterCode[
      Characters[dataIn]
      ], encoding
     ],
   "Text"
   ];
dataIn = Import["template.bat", "Text"];
test[dataIn, #] & /@ $CharacterEncodings;
```

but none of generated files works.
How can I handle them ?

Comment: Hi ! No, I was working on `template.bat` saved as ANSI. But now I'm testing the UTF-8 options. What's the operating system on your computer ?

Comment: My operating system is Windows XP, I'm migrating to Windows 10. Now I have tried template.bat saved as "template - ansi.bat", "template - utf8 whitput BOM.bat", "template - utf8.bat" but box drawing characters never are seen correctly when runnig generated files. Would you receive the involved files? Can I send them here or should I use dropbox, or similar site?